# An accented letter "i"

Tags: fonts, symbols

How can I make this symbol in latex?

[image: symbol]

Answer (score 2):

This way:
`\u{\i}`
For more info, see here:
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Special_Characters